# writing the first 10 words in linux.words (/usr/share/dict/words) to an array

Tags: c, arrays, list

So the linux.words file is a `\n` separated list of words. I've tried to access it with fopen as follows:

```
{
    FILE* words;

    words = fopen("~/usr/share/dict/words", "r");
    char* dictionary[10];
    if (words != NULL)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            fscanf(words, "%s", dictionary[i]); 
            printf("%s", dictionary[i])
        }
    }
}
```

I'm running in to a lot of trouble. I suspect it may have something to do with the fact that  I need to put something about `\n` in there, and also perhaps I haven't opened the file correctly.

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not allocating the space for the words that you are reading from the file.

```
char* dictionary[10];

...
// for each word
dictionary[i]= malloc(WORD_SIZE); 
...
```

Comment: okay...so now i've got

int main(void)
{
    FILE* words;
    words = fopen("~/usr/share/dict/words", "r");
    
    //479827 total words in this dictionary
    char* dictionary[10];
    if (words != NULL)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            dictionary[i]= malloc(8*sizeof(char));
            fscanf(words, "%s", dictionary[i]);
            printf("%s", dictionary[i]); 
        }
    }
}

It complies fine, but when i run it, nothing happens

Comment: are you sure the file is properly open?

Comment: I don't know ... how to check?

Answer (score 0):

You didnt allocate any space for your dictionaries

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you gave fopen() the wrong path. Try removing the tilde (~). Giuseppe's answer is also true, but I suspect your program did not even get that far.

It's good that you checked the return value of fopen() for an error (words != NULL). However, you should also do something, such as output a description of the error (e.g., with perror()). That will make debugging easier.